# What is a more efficient way to draw this tree?

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-qtree, forest

I have drawn the following tree in TikZ. What I don't like about it is

1. that I have to manually adjust the `sibling distance` for each level; and
2. the syntax is too cumbersome.

It has been suggested to me by @percusse and @AlanMunn that using `tikz-qtree` and/or `forest` may be a more efficient way to produce the same result. But I don't have experience in using either package.

It would be nice if someone can reproduce my example using either of these packages, so that I can have quick example to learn from instead of reading a 150-page manual trying to find an answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  % Two node styles for game trees: solid and hollow
  solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},
  hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2},
}

% macro for entering payoffs
\newcommand\payoff[1]{
  $\begin{pmatrix} #1 \end{pmatrix}$
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
  \tikzset{
    level 1/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=65mm},
    level 2/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=30mm},
    level 3/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=15mm},
    level 4/.style={level distance=15mm,sibling distance=10mm},
  }

  \node[hollow node,label=above:{Nature}]{}
    child{node[solid node,label=left:{P1}]{}
      child{node(l1)[solid node]{}
        child{node[solid node,label=below:{\payoff{1\\-1}}]{}edge from parent node[left]{L}}
        child{node[solid node,label=below:{\payoff{0\\0}}]{}edge from parent node[right]{R}}
        edge from parent node[left]{U}
      }
      child{node(l2)[solid node]{}
        child{node[solid node,label=below:{\payoff{0\\0}}]{}edge from parent node[left]{L}}
        child{node[solid node,label=below:{\payoff{2\\-2}}]{}edge from parent node[right]{R}}
        edge from parent node[right]{D}
      }
      edge from parent node[left,xshift=-10]{A}
    }
    child{node[solid node,label=right:{P1}]{}
      child{node(r1)[solid node]{}
        child{node[solid node,label=below:{\payoff{-2\\2}}]{}edge from parent node[left]{L}}
        child{node[solid node,label=below:{\payoff{0\\0}}]{}edge from parent node[right]{R}}
        edge from parent node[left]{U}
      }
      child{node(r2)[solid node]{}
        child{node[solid node,label=below:{\payoff{0\\0}}]{}edge from parent node[left]{L}}
        child{node[solid node,label=below:{\payoff{-1\\1}}]{}edge from parent node[right]{R}}
        edge from parent node[right]{D}
      }
      edge from parent node[right,xshift=10]{B}
    }
  ;

  \draw[dashed](l1)--(l2)--node[midway,above]{P2}(r1)--(r2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you at least tried to do something with `tikz-qtree` and/or `forest`. Converting the example to the `[`/`]` syntax might be the first thing to do …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Yes I've tried. My difficulty with `tikz-qtree` is adding the labels to the nodes and edges. I've never used `forest` before, and when I tried using `\tikzset` to set my node styles, I got an error. Still reading the `forest` manual trying to find out...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since this answer involves a different package, I've added it separately.  Here's a solution using the `forest` package.  The principles are similar, but I think that once you get used to the syntax, it might be a little easier to draw your trees using this package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\tikzset{
  % Two node styles for game trees: solid and hollow
  solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},
  hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2},
  % styles for long branch labels
  left label/.style={above left,midway},
  right label/.style={above right,midway}
}

% macro for entering payoffs
\newcommand\payoff[1]{
  $\begin{pmatrix} #1 \end{pmatrix}$
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[ ,for tree={s sep=.5in},label={Nature},hollow node
  [ ,for tree={solid node},edge label={node[left label]{A}}
        [ ,name=P2left,edge label={node[left label] {U}}
          [ ,label={below:\payoff{1\\-1}},edge label={node[left,midway] {L}} ]
          [ ,label={below:\payoff{0\\0}},edge label={node[right,midway] {R}} ] ]
        [ ,edge label={node[right label] {D}}
          [ ,label={below:\payoff{0\\0}},edge label={node[left,midway] {L}} ]
          [ ,label={below:\payoff{2\\-2}},edge label={node[right,midway] {R}} ] ]   
  ]
  [ ,for tree={solid node},edge label={node[right label]{B}}
  [ ,edge label={node[left label] {U}}
        [ ,label={below:\payoff{-2\\2}},,edge label={node[left,midway] {L}} ]
        [ ,label={below:\payoff{0\\0}},,edge label={node[right,midway] {R}} ]    
    ]
  [ ,name=P2right,edge label={node[right label] {D}}
    [ ,label={below:\payoff{0\\0}}, edge label={node[left,midway] {L}} ]
        [ ,label={below:\payoff{-1\\1}},,edge label={node[right,midway] {R}} ] ]
  ]
]
\draw[dashed] (P2left) --  node[above] {P2} (P2right);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I see. So `\tikzset` has to be used *outside* of the `forest` environment... Thanks again for the answers. They are very helpful!

Comment: `\forestset{
  left label/.style={
 edge label={node[left label]{#1}}
  },
  right label/.style={
 edge label={node[right label]{#1}}
  },
  where n children=0{
 if n=1{
   edge label={node[left,midway] {L}}
 }{
   edge label={node[right,midway] {R}}
 }
  }{}
}`

Answer (score 7):

This is not the answer you asked for but...

I (ab)use the *automata package* to write game trees because its structure and syntax are more intuitive than all the trees packages that are available.

This is how I would implement your example. (ps. later you can adapt it to label the information sets instead of the nodes by using option *pos* of **node**. Also you can fine tune the info. sets using the *in* and *out* options of **edge**.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,automata,trees,positioning,shadows,arrows,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,semithick]
\tikzstyle{every state}=[fill,draw=none,green,text=white,circular drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{accepting}=[circle split, draw,text=black,inner sep=0.05cm]
\tikzstyle{initial}=[red,text=white]

 \node[state,initial]   (0)  {Nature};
 \node[state]           (A) [below left of=0]  {P1};
 \node[state]               (B) [below right of=0] {P1};
 \node[state]           (AU) [left of=A]  {P2};
 \node[state]           (AD) [below of=A] {P2};
 \node[state]           (BU) [below  of=B]  {P2};
 \node[state]           (BD) [right of=B] {P2};
 \node[accepting]    (AUL) [above left of=AU] {$1$\nodepart{lower}$-1$};
 \node[accepting]    (AUR) [below left of=AU] {$0$\nodepart{lower}$0$};
 \node[accepting]    (ADL) [left of=AD]  {2\nodepart{lower}-2};
 \node[accepting]    (ADR) [below of=AD] {0\nodepart{lower}0};
 \node[accepting]    (BUL) [below of=BU]   {2\nodepart{lower}-2};
 \node[accepting]    (BUR) [right of=BU] {0\nodepart{lower}0};
 \node[accepting]    (BDL) [below right of=BD]  {0\nodepart{lower}0};
 \node[accepting]    (BDR) [above right of=BD] {$1$\nodepart{lower}$-1$};

\path(0) edge node[above]{A}(A) edge node[above]{B}(B);
\path(A) edge node[above]{U}(AU) edge node[left]{D}(AD);
\path(B) edge node[right]{U}(BU) edge node[above]{D}(BD);
\path(AU) edge node[above]{L}(AUL) edge node[left]{R}(AUR);
\path(AD) edge node[above left]{L}(ADL) edge node[right]{R}(ADR);
\path(BU) edge node[left]{L}(BUL) edge node[above]{R}(BUR);
\path(BD) edge node[below left]{L}(BDL) edge node[above left]{R}(BDR);
\path(AU) edge [-,dotted,thick,bend right] (AD);
\path(AD) edge [-,dotted,thick] (BU);
\path(BU) edge [-,dotted,thick,bend right] (BD);

 \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This type of  tree isn't a lot easier to draw with `tikz-qtree` since it was designed for drawing linguistic trees, the branches of which are almost never labelled.  To label an edge with `tikz-qtree` you have to draw each edge separately.  So it's hard to tell whether the following example using `tikz-qtree` will help you or not, but at least it should show you how you *could* do such a tree with the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\tikzset{
  % Two node styles for game trees: solid and hollow
  solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2,fill=black},
  hollow node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.2},
}

% macro for entering payoffs
\newcommand\payoff[1]{
  $\begin{pmatrix} #1 \end{pmatrix}$
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every level 0 node/.style={draw,hollow node},
                   every level 1 node/.style={draw,solid node},
                   every level 2 node/.style={draw,solid node},
                   every level 3 node/.style={draw,solid node},
                   level distance=.65in,
                   edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}]
\Tree [.\node[label={Nature}]{};  
        \edge node [auto=right ] {A}; [.\node[label=left:P1]{};
            \edge node [auto=right] {U}; [.\node (P2left) {};
                \edge node[auto=right] {L}; [.\node [label=below:{\payoff{1\\-1}}] {}; ]
                \edge node[auto=left] {R}; [.\node [label=below:{\payoff{0\\0}}] {}; ]]
            \edge node [auto=left] {D}; [.{} 
                \edge node[auto=right] {L}; [.\node [label=below:{\payoff{0\\0}}] {}; ]
                \edge node[auto=left] {R}; [.\node [label=below:{\payoff{2\\-2}}] {}; ]]] 
        \edge node [auto=left] {B}; [.\node[label=right:P2]{};
        \edge node [auto=right] {U}; [.{}
                \edge node[auto=right] {L}; [.\node [label=below:{\payoff{-2\\2}}] {}; ]
                \edge node[auto=left] {R}; [.\node [label=below:{\payoff{0\\0}}] {}; ]]
            \edge node [auto=left] {D}; [.\node (P2right) {}; 
                \edge node[auto=right] {L}; [.\node [label=below:{\payoff{0\\0}}] {}; ]
                \edge node[auto=left] {R}; [.\node [label=below:{\payoff{-1\\1}}] {}; ]]] ]
        ] 
\draw[dashed] (P2left) --  node[above] {P2} (P2right);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks like `tikz-qtree` wouldn't simplify the task too much. But the spacing is indeed much nicer now.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a somewhat unwise version which is hard to read or generalize, but is (at least to me) satisfyingly minimal.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\tikz[auto label/.style args={at #1 with #2}{
        label={[label distance=#1]\the\tikznumberofcurrentchild*180:#2}
    },
    dot/.style={inner sep=0.0625cm, circle, draw},
    every child node/.style={dot, fill},
    level distance=1.5cm,
    level/.style={sibling distance=6cm/(\tikztreelevel^1.25)}
]{
\node [dot, label=above:Nature, ] (tree) {}
    child foreach \n/\l [count=\a] in {P1/A, P1/B}{ 
        node [auto label=at 0cm with \n] {} 
        child foreach \l [count=\b] in {U, D}{ node {}  
            child foreach \l [count=\c, evaluate={\p=int(-(\b==\c)*((\a-1)*3-\c));\q=int(-\p);}] in {L, R} { 
                node [label=below:{$\begin{pmatrix}\p\\\q\end{pmatrix}$}] {}     
                edge from parent  coordinate [auto label=at 0cm with \l] 
            } 
            edge from parent  coordinate [auto label=at 0cm with \l] 
        }
        edge from parent coordinate [auto label=at 0.25cm with \l]   
    };
    \draw [dashed] (tree-1-1) -- (tree-2-2) node [midway, above] {P2};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is another solution using the [`istgame` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame?lang=en), which is based on TikZ. Since the `istgame` environment is almost the same as the `tikzpicture` environment, you can use any commands and options available in the `tikzpicture` within the `istgame` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
\xtShowEndPoints
\xtdistance{15mm}{50mm}
\istroot(0)[initial node]{Nature}
  \istb{A}[al]
  \istb{B}[ar]
  \endist
\xtdistance{15mm}{24mm}
\istroot(l)(0-1)<135>{P1}
  \istb{U}[l]
  \istb{D}[r]
  \endist
\istroot(r)(0-2)<45>{P1}
  \istb{U}[l]
  \istb{D}[r]
  \endist
\xtdistance{15mm}{12mm}
\istroot(l1)(l-1)
  \istb{L}[l]{\binom{1}{-1}}
  \istb{R}[r]{\binom{0}{0}}
  \endist
\istroot(l2)(l-2)
  \istb{L}[l]{\binom{0}{0}}
  \istb{R}[r]{\binom{2}{-2}}
  \endist
\istroot(r1)(r-1)
  \istb{L}[l]{\binom{-2}{2}}
  \istb{R}[r]{\binom{0}{0}}
  \endist
\istroot(r2)(r-2)
  \istb{L}[l]{\binom{0}{0}}
  \istb{R}[r]{\binom{-1}{1}}
  \endist
\xtInfoset[dashed](l1)(r2){P2}
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the addition, InSung! Your package looks amazing. I'll have to spend some time studying it.