# How do I align the last level of a tikZ \tree to the same height?

Tags: tikz-pgf

how do I get the very last hirachy of my tree to align to the same height? Every hierarchy before that is aligned but the last one differs.

Can you work with this code? I started working with TeX 5 weeks ago and it's the first time for me seeking help in a forum.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pdftex,twoside,9pt,paper=21cm:14.85cm,openright]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}                               
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata,shadows,fit,shapes}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}]
\Tree [.\textbf{Gießverfahren} 
                        [.{Schwerkraftgießen} 
                                        [.{Verlorene\\Formen} 
                                                [.{verlorene\\Modelle} \textit{Feingießen}\\\textit{Vollformgießem} ]
                                                [.{Dauermodelle} \textit{Sandgießen}\\\textit{Maskenformgießen} ]] 
                                        [.Dauerformen \textit{Kokillengießen}\\\textit{Stranggießen}\\\textit{Schleudergießen} ] ] 
                        [.{\textbf{Gießen unter Druck}} 
                                        [.{Verlorene\\Formen} \textit{Niederdruck-Sandgießen} ] 
                                        [.\textbf{Dauerformen} \textbf{Druckgießen}\\\textit{Niederdruckgießen}\\\textit{Gegendruckgießen}\\\textit{Sonderverfahren} ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, some of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Crosspost on texwelt.de: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/15366/letzte-ebene-einer-tikz-baumstruktur-auf-gleicher-hohe

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113395/how-do-i-skip-a-level-with-tikz-qtree

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using the `forest` package. It has the option `tier=word` that you can add to all the nodes you want to be aligned.

I have replaced some other minor details, feel free to ask for an explanation.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pdftex,twoside,9pt,paper=21cm:14.85cm,openright]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}                               
\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
    .style={
        for tree={
            base=bottom,
            parent anchor=south, 
            child anchor=north,
            align=center,
            s sep=.9mm,
            draw=none,
    if n children=0{tier=word, font=\itshape}{}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{forest}
    [ \textbf{Gieverfahren}
        [ Schwerkraftgieen
            [ Verlorene Formen 
                [ verlorene\\Modelle
                    [Feingieen\\Vollformgieen] ]
                [ Dauermodelle
                    [Sandgieen\\Maskenformgieen]] ] 
            [ Dauerformen 
                [Kokillengieen\\Stranggieen\\Schleudergieen] ] ]
        [ \textbf{Gieen unter Druck} 
            [ Verlorene Formen 
                [Niederdruck-Sandgieen] ] 
            [ \textbf{Dauerformen} 
                [\textbf{Druckgieen}\\Niederdruckgieen\\Gegendruckgieen\\Sonderverfahren] ] ] ]
\end{forest}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @cfr You were right, I didn't notice that. It does sound inefficiently redundant. I'll add the command to the `forestset`. :)

Answer (score 2):

`frontier` is a style which is applied to every leaf node. Assuming that 'the very last hierarchy' refers to these nodes i.e. the terminal nodes with no children, you can set this style to customise their appearance and placement.

To align these nodes, you need to specify an absolute distance from the root. (So this requires more fiddling than **forest** but allows you to work with your current code with few changes.)

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north},
    frontier/.style={distance from root=130pt}
  ]
  \Tree
  [.\textbf{Gießverfahren}
    [.{Schwerkraftgießen}
      [.{Verlorene\\Formen}
        [.{verlorene\\Modelle} \textit{Feingießen}\\\textit{Vollformgießem} ]
        [.{Dauermodelle} \textit{Sandgießen}\\\textit{Maskenformgießen} ]
      ]
      [.Dauerformen \textit{Kokillengießen}\\\textit{Stranggießen}\\\textit{Schleudergießen} ]
    ]
    [.{\textbf{Gießen unter Druck}}
      [.{Verlorene\\Formen} \textit{Niederdruck-Sandgießen} ]
      [.\textbf{Dauerformen} \textbf{Druckgießen}\\\textit{Niederdruckgießen}\\\textit{Gegendruckgießen}\\\textit{Sonderverfahren} ]
    ]
  ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: frontier leaves at set distance from root]

We can do something similar, but more flexibly, with **forest** by adapting [Alenanno's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/280806/):

```
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
```

This ensures that the edges to the children start from the same point, as this is not default for forest, and are drawn to the top centre of those children.

```
    align=center,
```

does the same as in **tikz-qtree**.

It would be good to ensure that the nodes on all levels are aligned by default, if that's what is wanted, rather than relying on it happening to come out that way. We can do this using the following code:

```
    tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},% align the nodes on all levels
```

We need to override this for the terminal nodes because we want them to be aligned despite being on different levels. So, for the leaf nodes, we set `tier=word` as in Alenanno's solution, but without having to remember to add it to each node:

```
    if n children=0{% for the leaf nodes
      tier=word,% override the default tier setting because these are at different levels of the tree but we want them still aligned
```

While we're here, we might as well set these in italic font and override the exception, rather than setting them all in upright and then overriding that in all but one case:

```
      font=\itshape,% make these nodes italic by default and we'll override this for the single exception
    }{}
}
```

[image: forest solution]

For an introduction to **forest** and its bracket syntax, see the second part of [my answer to an earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/how-can-i-draw-simple-trees-in-latex/254926?s=4|1.6521#254926).

**Forest** code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    align=center,
    tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},% align the nodes on all levels
    if n children=0{% for the leaf nodes
      tier=word,% override the default tier setting because these are at different levels of the tree but we want them still aligned
      font=\itshape,% make these nodes italic by default and we'll override this for the single exception
    }{}
  }
  [\textbf{Gieverfahren}
    [Schwerkraftgieen
      [Verlorene Formen
        [verlorene\\Modelle
          [Feingieen\\Vollformgieen
          ]
        ]
        [Dauermodelle
          [Sandgieen\\Maskenformgieen
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [Dauerformen
        [Kokillengieen\\Stranggieen\\Schleudergieen
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [\textbf{Gieen unter Druck}
      [Verlorene Formen
        [Niederdruck-Sandgieen
        ]
      ]
      [\textbf{Dauerformen}
        [\textbf{\upshape Druckgieen}\\Niederdruckgieen\\Gegendruckgieen\\Sonderverfahren
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Note that if you add `\itshape` inside the node, you need to do so after every line break, just as you would in **tikz-qtree** else only the first line will be set in italic.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to insert the missing levels:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside,fontsize=9pt,open=any]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{adieresis={ä},germandbls={ß}}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}]
\Tree [.\textbf{Gießverfahren} 
  [.{Schwerkraftgießen} 
    [.{Verlorene\\Formen} 
      [.{verlorene\\Modelle} \textit{Feingießen}\\\textit{Vollformgießem} ]
      [.{Dauermodelle} \textit{Sandgießen}\\\textit{Maskenformgießen} ]] 
        [.Dauerformen 
          [ 
            [.\textit{Kokillengießen}\\\textit{Stranggießen}\\\textit{Schleudergießen} ] ] ] ]
  [.{\textbf{Gießen unter Druck}} 
    [.{Verlorene\\Formen}
      [
        [.\textit{Niederdruck-Sandgießen} ] ] ]
    [.\textbf{Dauerformen} 
      [ 
        [.\textbf{Druckgießen}\\\textit{Niederdruckgießen}\\\textit{Gegendruckgießen}\\\textit{Sonderverfahren} ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]