# change node level tikz mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I would like to change the level of a specific node in a tikz mindmap, with something like `node[level=1]`, `[style=level 1/.style]`, or something like the [skip level style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147200/clear-and-readable-syntax-style-for-tikz-trees-with-edge-labels-and-options). I would like to avoid making an overlapping tree like in the [scientific interactions](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/scientific-interactions/) example.

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary[mindmap]

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,every node/.style=concept,text=white]
    \node {root}
        child {node {level 1 node}
            child {node {level 2 node}
            child[concept color=blue] {node {level 1 node}}
            child {node {level 3 node}}
            }
        }
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}            
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance :)

[image: the blue node should be level 1]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. In the case of a more complicated tree, how would TikZ decide to which node the child is to be attached?

Comment: In this case the node would still be a "level 3", although it's appearance would be that of a "level 2". A child to this node would then be a "level 4", so it would be necessary to change the style for each node in this branch. Actually what would be nice would be to be able to create a "parent" the same way we create a "child"...