# Left and right branching in the same tree with tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

Is it possible to have both right and left branching in the same tree with tikz-qtree? In the tree below I want the nodes F and G (and subsequently H and I) to be daughters of D, not E.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 

\Tree   
[.A [.B ] 
[.C [.D ]
[.E [.F ] 
[.G [.H ] [.I ]
 ] ] ] ]


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you looked at the [`forest`](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf) package? It's also Ti*k*Z and made to build trees. It's a very powerful tool on that matter and can definetely do what you are asking! See this question on efficient ways of making trees http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113315/what-is-a-more-efficient-way-to-draw-this-tree

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Since the problem here is converting a tree into the correct bracketed structure, `forest` would yield the same result with this tree.

Comment: @AlanMunn, true that!!! I totally disregard the code presented and automatically suggested `forest` beacuse it usually can manage things that `tikz` and `qtree` have difficult with. Shame on me... `;P`

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. Each pair of square brackets is a node, and anything inside that pair will be dominated by that node.  So this is just a matter of understanding how to turn a tree into a bracketed structure. It's helpful to use indenting to show the structure in your source code. I've removed the package `qtree` from your original code, since it's not needed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}

\Tree   
[.A [.B ] 
    [.C
        [.D
            [.F ]
            [.G
                [.H ]
                [.I ]
            ]
        ]
        [.E ]
    ]
]


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

To give you a better sense of the relation between the bracketing and the tree, here's your tree with brackets added to it. (This tree was created with `forest`, which is why it looks a little different.)

[image: annotated tree]